# Angular directive link function with 4 arguments?

Tags: angularjs

In Angular Developer Guide i find this example:

```
var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+$/;
app.directive('integer', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          ctrl.$setValidity('integer', true);
          return viewValue;
        } else {
          // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
          ctrl.$setValidity('integer', false);
          return undefined;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Q)** What is the fourth argument in the link function, and what does it bind to?
I thought the link function only take three arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's controller or array of controllers, specified in the `required` property of directive definition object. In this particular case it's controller of `ngModel` directive on the same element

[More info here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#require-directives)

Comment: Docs for `ngModelController`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController